# Construct a dynamic route path in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to construct a dynamic route path in ruby, something like this

```
    route = (a == a) ? "foo" : (b == b) ? "bar" : "default"
    link_to(event.try(:name), admin_"#{route}"_path('params goes here')
```

I very well know what I have tried is wrong. It should be done with dynamic method creations using class_eval or define_method I am not sure about that. Also, I am not familiar with those concepts. I can google but it would take much time to get a solution. 
Anyone, please help me solve this quickly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The method you look like is `polymorphic_path`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward:

```
send("admin_#{route}_path", params)
```

You may want to wrap that up in a helper method to clean things up:

```
def admin_path_for_ab(a, b, params = nil)
  route =
    if (a == 'a')
       "foo"
    elsif (b == 'b')
       "bar"
    else
       "default"
    end

  send("admin_#{route}_path", params)
end
```

As a note, nesting ternaries (`x ? y : z`) is usually a bad idea, and `a == a` is always true.

Comment: Thanks a lot @tadman, It works fine as I expected. Yeah, I will move the code to helper and (a==a) I just gave it for an example. Thanks once again.!!